# How to archive recursively only files with diferences from two compared folders shell

Tags: shell, diff, archive, tar

I  was  looking  to archive recursively only files  with differences from two compared src folders in shell. This  can  help  to  highlight  changes performed  when  sharing  files  for  review.  Bellow  is  shown  a  snipet of  code  I wrote  to  solve  this problem.

Q:  is  there any other  way  to  do  same with  diff ?

Code:

```
for  file in `find new_src -type f -name *java`; do
      file2="${file/new_src/src}"
      if ! diff -q "${file}" "${file2}" > /dev/null  2>&1; then
       tar  -uvf  new_src.tar "${file}"
       tar  -uvf  src_orig.tar "${file2}"
      fi
     echo 
 done
```

Comment: It looks ok. You could add quotes around variables. If you want efficiency, you could bunch up files and tar them together (tar-updating one file at a time takes time).

Comment: adding accolades and  quotes